# Count Unique Text Based on 2 Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I was playing around with a couple ideas to count unique text based on two criteria. I was thinking Sumproduct would do it for me, but it doesn't seem to work. I may need some kind of VBA script.  Basically, I want to do the following.

1)  Look at everything in ColumnB and if that matches a criteria

2)  Look at everything in ColumnW and if that matches a criteria

3)  Count unique text in ColumnF.

It's almost like this:

=COUNTIFS(W:W,A1,B:B,B1)

THEN, based on the result of that, count uniques in ColumnF

I was thinking this should be pretty easy, but it's turning out to be really hard!

Comment: What are the Criteria?  Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Please post an example of your data, and your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [standard SUMPRODUCT-based pseudo-COUNTUNIQUE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b) but you need to modify it by adding the criteria in the numerator and also the inverse criteria in the demononator; the latter to avoid `#DIV/0!` errors. This will generate a pseudo-COUNTIFSUNIQUE.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((B2:B20="bee")*(W2:W20="double-you"))/
           (COUNTIFS(B2:B20, "bee", W2:W20, "double-you", F2:F20, F2:F20)+(B2:B20<>"bee")+(W2:W20<>"double-you")))
```

[image: countifsunique]

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the slowness immediately.  I just need ROWS 1:16100, so I'm using just that range.  I decided to use the solution Alexis posted since it's so much faster.  One final question.  How can I modify this to say, show me everything that matches one criteria, doesn't match five criteria, and counts the unique.  So, match crit1, don't match crit2 to crit6, and show uniques in ColumnF?  Maybe it's just a count of all uniques, by crit1, and subtract out crit2 to crit6.  That would do it!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to adapt the formula from here: [Count Unique Text Values in a Range](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range).

Instead of using `F:F`, you modify it to match `F:F` if both `Crit1` and `Crit2` hold and `"No Match"` otherwise. That is,

```
IF((B:B="Crit1")*(W:W="Crit2"),F:F,"No Match")
```

Then you do a unique count on that array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(IF((B:B="Crit1")*(W:W="Crit2"),F:F,"No Match"),
                               IF((B:B="Crit1")*(W:W="Crit2"),F:F,"No Match"),0),
                         ROW(F:F)-ROW($F$1)+1)>0))
 -NOT(PRODUCT((B:B="Crit1")*(W:W="Crit2")))
```

The `-NOT(PRODUCT(...))` at the end is to subtract the unique count for the `"No Match"` entry if it exists (this can be replaced by just `-1` if you know there will always be things that don't match both criteria).

Note that this is an array formula and must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Seems to work well but those full column references slow it down substantially. A warning note recommending cutting the full column references down to the worksheet's [.UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) might be appropriate.

Comment: Very true. They definitely should be cut down to an appropriate range. I posted them that way for readability and since I don't know the particular rows OP is using.